# Rename .net solution and folders

Tags: .net, rename, directory, solution

I want to rename my solution and project and it worked in visual studio but it did not change the name in the folder, so when I manually change the name my project won't run because he's still looking for the files before they were renamed. I want to change the yellow to the same name of the red (Projecten2)

[image: I want to change the yellow to the same name of the red (Projecten2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the project from the solution, then rename the folder to whatever you chose for your new project name, and then add it to the solution again.